# Magic Zoom z-index issue with IE 9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, z-index, magiczoom

Has anyone experienced a z-index problem with [Magic Zoom](http://www.magictoolbox.com/magiczoom/) on IE 8 or 9?

I have an element with `z-index: 1`
MagicZoom creates an element with `z-index: 100`
However IE9 displays the element with z-index 1 on top of the 100.

Here is [the page](http://famous.fbstest.com.au/CustomPages/zindex1.html).

The weird thing is, I can no longer reproduce the problem if I "freeze" the condition and removing magiczoom.js. Here is [the result](http://famous.fbstest.com.au/CustomPages/zindex.html), perfect even on IE 9.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: what handler binds the output to what div? i am having trouble understanding where you are binding the "zoom" too.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for looking at it, sorry I'm not sure what you mean. The js will modify a.MagicZoom

Comment: So you have a javascript thats binded too the a tag. So where does the output get binded too?

Comment: Sorry what does 'binded' mean? This is a 3rd party script I didn't write it.

Comment: So think of two parameters. Input, what you are passing the script (the <a> tag) --- and output (the zoomed in version <div> container). That container should be referenced for the output of the zoomed in version of the image no?

Comment: I don't know what the script does exactly, but using "inspect element" I tried copying what it did (http://famous.fbstest.com.au/CustomPages/zindex.html) however I could not reproduce the z-index problem.

Comment: You can position the zoomed image literally anywhere on your page if you give it a unique id and reference it with the div. Place your div anywhere in your code and position it with CSS. Example HTML:

Zoom

`<a href="big.jpg" class="MagicZoom" rel="zoom-position:#yourzoom"><img src="small.jpg"/></a>
<div id="yourzoom"></div>`

Comment: so I would suggest to add targeting div to body and set it's position via css

Comment: @eicto You're the man! Thanks so much!!! Could you please cut and paste your comment into an answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation says:

---

You can position the zoomed image literally anywhere on your page if you give it a unique id and reference it with the div. Place your div anywhere in your code and position it with CSS. Example HTML: Zoom

```
<a href="big.jpg" class="MagicZoom" rel="zoom-position:#yourzoom">
    <img src="small.jpg"/>
</a> 
<div id="yourzoom"></div>
```

---

so I would suggest to add targeting div to body and set it's position via css
Or you can try to add target div to `td` element, but if table will have other rows/collumns problem will probably reappear.

Comment: I noticed I wasn't using the latest version because zoom-position doesn't work. Upgrading to the latest version fixed the bug without even changing the zoom-position. Thanks a lot eicto!

Answer (score 0):

You are using version 3.1.18 of Magic Zoom which is 3 years old.

This issue will be resolved if you upgrade to the latest version: 4.0.19.